# Replacing elements in a list of lists

Tags: r, replace

The `apply` functions in R are a nice way to simplify for loops to get to an output. Is there an equivalent function that helps one avoid for loops when replacing the values of a vector? This is better understood by example...

```
# Take this list for example
x = list( list(a=1,b=2), list(a=3,b=4), list(a=5,b=6) )

# To get all of the "a" elements from each list, I can do
vapply(x,"[[",1,"a")
[1] 1 3 5

# If I want to change all of the "a" elements, I cannot do
vapply(x,"[[",1,"a") = 10:12
Error in vapply(x, "[[", 1, "a") = 10:12 : 
  could not find function "vapply<-"
# (this error was expected)

# Instead I must do something like this...
new.a = 10:12
for(i in seq_along(x)) x[[i]]$a = new.a[i]
```

Is there a simpler or faster alternative to using a loop?

Comment: Does the result need to stay as a list?

Comment: Yes. This requirement is partly why it has been difficult for me to find an alternative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option would be to first `unlist` the list `x`, then replace the values named `"a"`, and then `relist` the new list `u` based on the list structure of `x`.

```
u <- unlist(x)
u[names(u) == "a"] <- 10:12
relist(u, x)
```

Comment: +1 thanks for bringing `relist` to my attention as well.

Answer (score 2):

`vapply` is a special case of `sapply` where you need to pre-specify the return type.

If you a multivariate version of `sapply`, the function you are looking for is `mapply` (or `Map` which is a wrapper with SIMPLIFY=FALSE`)

In general, functions with side-effects are frowned upon in R. The standard approach would be to create a new object when modifying.

You could use `modlifyList` to perform the modifications

```
xnew <- Map(modifyList, x, val = lapply(10:12,function(x) list(a = x)))
```

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, I tested this `Map`/`modifyList` approach with `microbenchmark` and it's about 2.5x slower than a loop on my computer. I didn't find this surprising, but I'm not only looking for speed. I like your solution!

Comment: @kdauria Talk a look at `Map` in your console. It's just a wrapper for `mapply`, and `mapply` is just a loop.