# Change data type of elements in a nested list

Tags: r

Is it possible to scan a list of lists for elements with a certain name and change their datatype but retain their value?

As an example, the following list containing elements 'N' of class 'character' or 'numeric'

```
x = list(list(N=as.character(1)),
         list(a=1,b=2,c="another element",N=as.character(5)), 
         list(a=2,b=2,N=as.character(7),c=NULL), 
         list(a=2,b=2,list(N=as.character(3))))
```

should then become:

```
x = list(list(N=as.numeric(1)),
         list(a=1,b=2,c="another element",N=as.numeric(5)), 
         list(a=2,b=2,N=as.numeric(7),c=NULL), 
         list(a=2,b=2,list(N=as.numeric(3))))
```

To be clear, the solution should allow for deeper nesting, and respect the data type of fields with names other than "N". I have not been able to find a general solution that works for lists with an arbitrary structure.

I have tried something along the lines of the solution given in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23420331/replacing-elements-in-a-list-of-lists):

```
a <- as.relistable(x)
u <- unlist(a)
u[names(u) == "N"] <- as.numeric(u[names(u) == "N"])
relist(u, a)
```

Unfortunately the substitution does not work in it's current form. In addition, relist does not seem to work in case the list contains NULL elements.

Comment: I can't see how this can be done for an arbitrary complexity. You could coerce ALL characters to numeric using `rapply`, e.g. `rapply(x, as.numeric, how = "replace")`.

Comment: Yes, but this as this solution changes all elements, it would not work for arbitrary complexity - I have changed the example to make this clearer

Answer (score 1):

Use `lapply` to repeat the process over the list elements with a condition to check for your element of interest, so you don't inadvertently add elements to your sublists:

```
x <- lapply(x, function(i) {

    if(length(i$N) > 0) {

        i$N <- as.numeric(i$N)

    }

    return(i)

})
```

Comment: I initially tried this too, but this  unfortunately doesn't work for lists where N is located at an arbitrary depth. I've changed the example to make this aspect clearer.

Comment: Huh, it should work no matter where `N` is in each list, or whether there is an `N`. How does it fail?

Comment: it fails if N is nested more than one level deep. I guess a reciprocal version would work on lists with a nesting>1

Comment: Ah, okay. So you revised the question to extend to lists of lists of lists, not just lists of lists.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works only on a list of lists containing numbers or strings with numbers:

```
x <- list(list(N=as.character(1)),
         list(a=1,b=2,N=as.character(5)), 
         list(a=2,b=2,N=as.character(7)), 
         list(a=2,b=2))

y1 <- lapply(x, function(y) lapply(y, as.numeric))

y2 <- list(list(N=as.numeric(1)),
         list(a=1,b=2,N=as.numeric(5)), 
         list(a=2,b=2,N=as.numeric(7)), 
         list(a=2,b=2))

identical(y1,y2)
# [1] TRUE
```

**EDIT.** Here is a more general code that works on nested lists of number and strings. It uses a recursive function `as_num` and the `list.apply` function of the `rlist` package.

```
library(rlist)

x = list(list(N=as.character(1)),
         list(a=1,b=2,c="another element",N=as.character(5)), 
         list(a=2,b=2,N=as.character(7),c=NULL), 
         list(a=2,b=2,list(N=as.character(3))))

# Test if the string contains a number
is_num <- function(x) grepl("[-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*|[-]?[0-9]+[L]?|[-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*[eE][0-9]+",x)

# A recursive function for numeric convertion of strings containing numbers
as_num <- function(x) {
   if (!is.null(x)) {
     if (class(x)!="list") {
       y <- x
       if (is.character(x) & is_num(x)) y <- as.numeric(x)
     } else {
       y <- list.apply(x, as_num)
     }
   } else { 
     y <- x
   }
   return(y)
}

y <- list.apply(x, as_num)

z = list(list(N=as.numeric(1)),
         list(a=1,b=2,c="another element",N=as.numeric(5)), 
         list(a=2,b=2,N=as.numeric(7),c=NULL), 
         list(a=2,b=2,list(N=as.numeric(3))))

identical(y,z)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: This indeed works for the example, but not for more complex lists. I have change the example to make this clearer.

Comment: I will do so next time. While I indeed failed to reflect this in the example, the original question already stated that I was looking for a solution that would also work for more complex lists.

Comment: @JoostKeuskamp I have tested the code on nested lists more complex than your examples and it works. Nevertheless, I would be interested to know if it works also on your nested lists.

Comment: @marcSandri It was a very good start, but failed in case of my lists. I'll post an additional answer with a working code based on yours if that's OK.

Comment: Edit your old question  adding  your lists at the end of che text. Write EDIT to clearly show che addition.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by [marco sandri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1166684/marco-sandri) can be further generalised to:

```
is_num <- function(x) grepl("^[-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*|^[-]?[0-9]+[L]?|^[-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*[eE][0-9]+",x)

as_num <- function(x) {
if (is.null(x)||length(x) == 0) return(x)
if (class(x)=="list") return(lapply(x, as_num))
if (is.character(x) & is_num(x)) return(as.numeric(x))
return(x)
}
y <- as_num(z)
identical(y,z)
```

This solution also allows for list elements to contain numerical(0) and mixed datatypes such as 'data2005'.